# UCWA return different presence under different logins

Tags: rest, lync, skype-for-business, ucwa

I use UCWA in my project to get presence information from Lync (Skype for business). The problem is, when i use one login to get access to UCWA, I get all the presence info I get when a using Lync client. But when I use another login, 80% off presence responses are "None", despite that lot of them must be "Online". The same picture is in Lync client 
Seems Lync server configuration problem for me. What could be done to solve this?

Comment: Are these users on different pools?  Are the users with incorrect presence federated users?

Comment: The logins are on same pool and both have presence federation with all users

Comment: How are you getting all the presence data for the user's contacts?  If you get the contactPresence Uri for a contact and execute a GET request are you seeing the correct presence value reported?

Comment: I have list of user's URIs, then I get contactPresence one by one, for most of users I have "None" for presence in JSON response. But then I quickly switch to other login, and receive "Online", "Away" or "Offline" for those users with "None"

Comment: Have you tried using a [presenceSubscription](http://ucwa.skype.com/documentation/KeyTasks-People-SubscribeToGroupPresence) to see if the values returned by the event channel might differ?

Comment: Just tried that, for person who return "None" for presence presenceSubscription doesn't work too